# Next.js redirect old-url to new-url next.config problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to redirect a route for my Nextjs app.
For example, I have route something like below:

**domain-name.com/keyword?=type_anything**

I want to replace it with something like the below:

**domain-name.com/type_anything**

I'm trying something like below by using **next.config.js**:

```
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/keyword?=:slug',
                destination: '/:slug',
                permanent: true,
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: The first route is not just a route: that's a route + a query parameter to be precise. If the list of all possible slugs is known, maybe you could try to compute an array of redirections? But otherwise, you might want to create a `[keyword].jsx` dynamic page that handles the redirect in `getServerSideProps`, it will give you more control on the redirection process, including checking query parameters or route parameters.

Comment: yes, I know all possible glugs. The slugs are looks like below:
`domain-name.com/keyword?=mobile
domain-name.com/keyword?=iphone`
... same as 100's of slugs
I just want to redirect it like below:
`domain-name.com/mobile`
domain-name.com/iphone